# How to Display the Sales and Other Department Sales Seperatly on Tally

Tags: tally

hope you all are good .I new to tally and I have a new situation ,I have provided the details below 
1.we Own a supermarket and which contains some other departments as well 
2.only one counter is available for this supermarket section 
3.so the sales of other departments also get mixed with the total sale

Task :- when I enter this data into tally I have to show the other departments sales seperatly on balance sheet, how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The Profit & Loss statement in Tally shows you the sales data of every Sales ledger separately. So, to have data on separate sales for separate departments, you will have to make different sales ledgers for different departments and make the entries accordingly.

If you are using combined single ledger for all sales, then you should make three ledgers now for sales of each of the three departments. If you are using sales ledger item wise or tax slab wise, then you need to create similar ledgers for every department and take care of choosing the right ledger when creating the voucher.